# Cannot define key binding in `markdown-mode`

Tags: key-bindings, package, markdown-mode

I'm trying to use the package [**checkbox**](https://github.com/camdez/checkbox.el) together with `markdown-mode`. The **checkbox** documentation gives the following example on how to define a global key binding for it's functionality:

```
I'd recommend globally binding checkbox-toggle to a convenient keystroke:

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-t") 'checkbox-toggle)
```

Although this does indeed work for all other modes, it does not seem to work with `markdown-mode`. While in `markdown-mode`, entering the `C-c C-t` keystroke simply waits for me to provide additional keystrokes (i.e. it's undefined according to emacs). Any ideas for why this happens, or how to fix it?

(I'm sorry if there is an obvious way to do this or find information about this problem, I'm a bit of an beginner)

Comment: Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file) and then load only library checkbox? If not, recursively bisect your init file to find out what is causing the problem.

Comment: Some other bindings for the `checkbox-toggle` do seem to work btw

Comment: Another possibility: do `C-c C-t C-h` and check the commands that are (apparently) bound on prefix key `C-c C-t`. Their names will likely point you to some library that defines `C-c C-t` as a prefix key. If so, you have a choice: Don't use `C-c C-t` as a prefix key or bind `checkbox-toggle` to some key other than `C-c C-t`.

Comment: Other keymaps take priority over global keymap bindings. Some mode (major or minor) is likely defining `C-c C-t` as a prefix key. See above. You can bind `checkbox-toggle` to any key you want, but if you bind it only in the global keymap and there is a collision with a binding in another map, the other-map binding wins.

Comment: All right, thanks for the info! I found the conflict, i'll see if i can resolve it in some way (preferably using the `C-c C-t` binding).

Comment: If you want to use `C-c C-t` for `checkbox-toggle` in `markdown-mode` then you could bind it to that key in `markdown-mode-map`. But that will prevent it acting as a prefix key...

Comment: Thank you, that about did what I wanted! `C-c C-t` ended up having quite some important usage within `markdown-mode` however, so I share your concern about redefining it. If you want I'll accept your last comment as an answer, i.e. redefining `C-c C-t` to nil using `markdown-mode-map` so that I'll be able to use it for `checkbox-toggle` instead.

Comment: Put that in your question or as another answer. Comments risk being deleted at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `C-c C-t` for `checkbox-toggle` in `markdown-mode` then you could bind it to that key in `markdown-mode-map`. But that will prevent it acting as a prefix key...

(Why don't you just bind it to some other, unused key?)